# What is Owned Entity? When and why to use Owned Entity in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm learning Entity Framework Core. I came across the term "Owned Entity" in almost all tutorials.

Here is one example on using an Owned Entity in Entity Framework Core

**Job Entity:**

```cs
public class Job : Entity
{
    public HiringManagerName HiringManagerName { get; private set; }
}
```

**HiringManagerName Value Object:**

```cs
public class HiringManagerName : ValueObject
{
    public string First { get; }
    public string Last { get; }

    protected HiringManagerName()
    {
    }

    private HiringManagerName(string first, string last)
        : this()
    {
        First = first;
        Last = last;
    }

    public static Result<HiringManagerName> Create(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName))
            return Result.Failure<HiringManagerName>("First name should not be empty");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
            return Result.Failure<HiringManagerName>("Last name should not be empty");

        firstName = firstName.Trim();
        lastName = lastName.Trim();

        if (firstName.Length > 200)
            return Result.Failure<HiringManagerName>("First name is too long");
        if (lastName.Length > 200)
            return Result.Failure<HiringManagerName>("Last name is too long");

        return Result.Success(new HiringManagerName(firstName, lastName));
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return First;
        yield return Last;
    }
}
```

**Entity Configuration:**

```cs
public class JobConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Job>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Job> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(p => p.HiringManagerName, p =>
        {
            p.Property(pp => pp.First)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("HiringManagerFirstName")
                .HasMaxLength(200);
            p.Property(pp => pp.Last)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("HiringManagerLastName")
                .HasMaxLength(200);
        });
    }
}
```

And this gets created as two columns in table like other columns in `Job Entity`.

[image]

Since this is also created as columns just like other properties in entity this can directly be added as normal properties in the Job Entity. Why this needs to be added as Owned Entity?

Please can anyone help me understand,

1. What is owned entity?
2. Why we need to use owned entity?
3. When to use owned entity?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## What does this look like without owned entities?

If you create an entity, `Job`, in EF Core that points to a complex object, `HiringManagerName`, in one of the properties, EF Core will expect that each will reside in a separate table and will expect you to define some sort of relationship between them (e.g. one-to-one, one-to-many, etc.).

When retrieving `Job`, if you want to explicitly load the values of `HiringManagerName` as well, you'd have to use an explicit `Include` statement in the query or it will not be populated.

```
var a = dbContext.Jobs
.Include(b => b.HiringManagerName) //Necessary to populate
.ToListAsync();
```

But because each is thought to be a separate entity, they will be required to expose keys and you'll have to configure foreign keys between each.

## What is an owned entity?

That's where `[Owned]` types come in (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)). By marking the child class with the `[Owned]` attribute, you leave the explicit handling of that relationship to EF Core to manage and no longer have a need to define the key(s)/foreign key(s) on the owned type. Same if you point to a collection of your owned type - you no longer need to deal with navigation properties on either class to describe the relationship.

EF Core also supports queries against these owned types, as in:

```
var job = context.Jobs.Where(a => a.HiringManagerName.First == "fingers10").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Now, it comes with two important [design restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#limitations) described in the docs (but elaborated on here):

- You cannot create a DbSet for the owned type

This means that you cannot subsequently do a DB call with:

```
dbContext.HiringManagerNames.ToListAsync();
```

This will throw because you are expected to simply retrieve the value as part of a call to:

```
dbContext.Jobs.ToListAsync();
```

Unlike the first example I gave, `HiringManagerNames` no longer needs to be explicitly included and will instead be returned with a call to the Jobs `DbSet<T>`.

- Cannot call `Entity<T>` with an owned type on `ModelBuilder`

Similarly, you cannot reference your owned type in the ModelBuilder to configure it. Rather, if you must configure it, do so through the configuration against your Jobs entity and against the owned property, e.g.:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().OwnsOne(a => a.HiringManagerNames).//Remaining configuration
```

## So when should I use owned entities?

If you've got a type that's only ever going to appear as a navigation property of another type (e.g. you're never querying against it itself as the root entity of the query), use owned types in order to save yourself some relationship boilerplate.

If you ever anticipate querying the child entity independent of the parent, don't make it owned - it will need to be defined with its own `DbSet<T>` in order to be called from the context.

Comment: What do owned objects look like in the DB? Are they in the database at all? How does EF handle this "explicit relationship." Or does owned just mean we will manage it in code?

Comment: @Morgeth888 Per the documentation, whether it's all stored in the same or separate tables is something that's configurable by yourself (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#storing-owned-types-in-separate-tables) from the `modelBuilder`. Based on that configuration, EF handles the setup of this relationship differently, but no differently than if you were to do it yourself. It's simply offering a convenient approach to trivially accessing related data that should always bundle with that which you created a DbSet for but which you'd not independently query for.

Answer (score 7):

While @Whit Waldo explanation is great with respect to technical ef core, we should also try to understand from [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) perspective.

Lets observe the classes mentioned in the question itself

```
public class Job : Entity
```

and

```
public class HiringManagerName : ValueObject
```

Take a note at *Entity* and *ValueObject*. Both of them are DDD concepts.

Identity matters for entities, but does not matter for value objects.

Take a look at [this write up from Vladimir Khorikov for a more extensive explanation](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/entity-vs-value-object-the-ultimate-list-of-differences/).

I past the summary bullets here.

- Entities have their own intrinsic identity, value objects don’t.
- The notion of identity equality refers to entities; the notion of structural equality refers to value objects; the notion of reference equality refers to both.
- Entities have a history; value objects have a zero lifespan.
- ***A value object should always belong to one or several entities, it can’t live by its own.***
- Value objects should be immutable; entities are almost always mutable.
- To recognize a value object in your domain model, mentally replace it with an integer.
- Value objects shouldn’t have their own tables in the database.
- Always prefer value objects over entities in your domain model.

So a value object is owned by an entity. So how do we achieve that using EF Core? Here comes the concept of Owned entities. Now go back and read @Whit Waldo answer.